# CREATE TRIGGER without SUPER privilege on cloudcontrol.com

Tags: mysql, cloudcontrol

When I try to create a trigger for my mysqls database addon on cloudcontrol.com I get the following error:

> ERROR 1419 (HY000): You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary
>   logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe
>   log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

So, is there really no way for me to use triggers? That's frustrating. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling trigger is only possible with the [`MySQLd addon`](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Add-on%20Documentation/Data%20Storage/MySQLd), for this we have to enable the [log_bin_trust_function_creators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_bin_trust_function_creators). Be aware that this can cause some problems with insecure triggers. You can find more information in the mysql documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I suspected that the MySQLd addon is the only solution. But for my private non-commercial site 50 € / month for the micro plan is too much. So, I think I have to implement the trigger logic in the application layer as a workaround.